# How do I add another 0 in my float output "$7.0" using format() in Python

Tags: python, string, function, format

```
def cash_converter():
        integer = input("enter an integer: ")  # Prompt user for integer input: 7
        sentence = "That is ${}".format(float(integer))
        print(sentence)
```

**My Output:**

enter an integer: 7

That is $7.0

**Expected Output:**

enter an integer: 7

That is $7.00

Answer (score 1):

(:."number"f) will determine the number of deicimels.

Change

```
sentence = "That is ${}".format(float(integer))
```

to

```
sentence = "That is ${:.2f}".format(float(integer))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways that you can do this the way that I would do it is like this

```
print(format(7, ",.2f"))
```

This will format the value to the 2 decimal place.